# Using std::find_if() with a comparison function that takes multiple input parameters

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use the `std::find_if()` algorithm with a comparison function that takes multiple input arguments, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code. I have searched for usages of `std::find_if()` on various sites, but all of them used a comparison function with a single input argument.

```
using namespace std;

// comparison function
bool range_search(double x, double X1, double X2)
{
    return (x >= X1 && x <= X2) ? true : false;
}

// main   
vector<double> x;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    x.push_back(...);
};

vector<double>::iterator it = find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), range_search);
int pos_1 = distance(x.begin(), it);
```

Comment: are X1 and X2 constants?

Comment: Use lambdas or functor objects?

Comment: @P.W yes, X1 & X2 are constants. But I want to call this function a couple of times. e.g X[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}}; for 1st case: X1 = X[0][0], X2 = X[0][1] & for 2nd case X1 = X[1][0], X2 = X[1][1].

Comment: If you look on [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) you can see the concept for the predicate function is `UnaryPredicate`. So the standard library function will only accept a function that accepts one argument and returns true/false. Your function takes 3 arguments. So you need to wrap it with a function that takes just one.

Comment: Are you allowed to use at least the C++11 standard?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, I can use C++11 standard.

Answer (score 9):

There is no version of `std::find_if()` that accepts a predicate with multiple input arguments.  `std::find_if()` iterates through the specified iterator range, passing each element one at a time to the predicate.  As such, the predicate must take only 1 input argument, no more, no less. That is why all of the examples you have seen use 1 argument.

The `range_search()` function you have shown is simply not compatible to use as the predicate itself.

In C++11 and later, you can use a lambda to capture the extra values you want to pass to `range_search()`, eg:

```
double X1 = ...;
double X2 = ...;
auto it = find_if(x.begin(), x.end(),
    [X1, X2](double x){ return range_search(x, X1, X2); }
);
```

Prior to C++11, you can use a functor object instead:

```
struct range_search_s
{
    double X1, X2;
    range_search_s(double x1, double x2) : X1(x1), X2(x2) {}
    bool operator()(double x) { return range_search(x, X1, X2); }
};

double X1 = ...;
double X2 = ...;
vector<double>::iterator it = find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), range_search_s(X1, X2));
```

Answer (score 6):

`find_if` requires only one argument to its test function because it has to test each element in the collection in turn.  If you want to bind extra variables at call time, use a lambda:

```
double X1 = 2, X2 = 4;
auto it = find_if(x.begin(), x.end(),
                  [&](double v) { return (v >= X1 && v <= X2); });
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is mostly useful for pre-C++11. With C++11 or newer, I suggest to [use a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530609/7571258) for readability.

You can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to turn a function with `n` parameters into one with `n-x` parameters by supplying some of the arguments as constants:

```
auto fn = std::bind(&range_search, _1, 0.1, 0.9);
```

The `_1` is a placeholder for the first argument, which we want to keep variable. The arguments `0.1` and `0.9` are passed for parameters `X1` and `X2` respectively.

As the generated function now has only one parameter, we can use it with `std::find_if()`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), fn);
```

You can also combine the two into a single call:

```
auto it = std::find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::bind(&range_search, _1, 0.1, 0.9));
```

**[Live Demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa8416b4ae3d26b6)**

Answer (score 1):

Given that `std::find_if` accepts only an unary predicate, you can construct one using an higher order function with multiple input arguments returning an unary lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

namespace pred {

template <class T>
constexpr auto is_in_range(const T min_value, const T max_value)
{
    return [min_value, max_value] (T x) { return x >= min_value && x <= max_value; };
}

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x {0.1, -3.0, 1.67, 4.0, 3.14, 1.5, 0.0, 2.0};

    auto it = find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), pred::is_in_range(1.0, 3.0));
    assert(distance(x.begin(), it) == 2  &&  *it == 1.67);  

    auto ranged = pred::is_in_range(0.0, 3.5);

    auto it2 = find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), ranged);   
    assert(distance(x.begin(), it2) == 0  &&  *it2 == 0.1);  

    std::vector<double> y;
    std::copy_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::back_inserter(y), ranged);
    assert(y.size() == 6);

    std::cout << "So far, so good...\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda:

```
vector<double>:: iterator it = find_if(x.begin(),x.end(),[param1, param2, param3](const double& a, const double& b) { /* use param1-3 here*/ });
```

Comment: You can't use 2 parameter values between the `()` of the lambda, `find_if()` will only accept 1 parameter there.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, we use a combination of templates, lambdas, and a custom compare function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename R = typename std::vector<T>::iterator>
R Find(std::vector<T> &vector, T &key, bool F(T &, T &))
{
    return std::find_if(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [&](T &f) { return F(key, f); });
}

class Type
{
public:
    int X = 0;

    int Y = 0;

    Type(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

bool compare(Type &a, Type &b)
{
    return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y;
}

auto nodes = std::vector<Type> = {Type(1, 1), Type(2, 1) };
auto node = Type(2, 1);

auto result = Find(nodes, node, compare) != nodes.end();
```

The compare function takes in two parameters (both of which are data type: **Type**). The template Find function searches the vector (of **Type**'s) for the specific item, using the custom compare function (**F** in the template). It returns an iterator whether or not the item was found. Finally if the iterator does not point to the end() of the vector, then it means that the item is present in the vector.

**Limitations**: This does not work when the number of parameters is variable.